# How do I fix this InvalidArgumentError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working on this chess algorithm for my machine learning class, but I'm not sure what's going wrong. I'm following a video [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffzvhe97J4Q), but it seems everything goes wrong when I try to fit my model. I've attached the code below, which sets up a chess board and then a convolutional network. I keep getting the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph Execution Error which points to model.fit(x_train, y_train). 
The size of x_train is (150000, 14, 8, 8) while y_train is (150000, )
```

Code:

```
 def random_board(max_depth=200):
        board = chess.Board()
        depth = random.randrange(0, max_depth)
        
        for _ in range(depth):
            all_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
            random_move = random.choice(all_moves)
            board.push(random_move)
            if board.is_game_over():
                break
        return board          
    
    
      squares_index = {
          'a': 0,
          'b': 1,
          'c': 2,
          'd': 3,
          'e': 4,
          'f': 5,
          'g': 6,
          'h': 7
        }
        
        
        # example: h3 -> 17
        def square_to_index(square):
            letter = chess.square_name(square)
            return 8 - int(letter[1]), squares_index[letter[0]]
        
        
        def split_dims(board):
          # create empty 3d matrix for board 
            board3d = numpy.zeros((14, 8, 8), dtype=numpy.int8)
          # here we add the pieces's view on the matrix
            for piece in chess.PIECE_TYPES:
                for square in board.pieces(piece, chess.WHITE):
                    idx = numpy.unravel_index(square, (8, 8))
                    board3d[piece - 1][7 - idx[0]][idx[1]] = 1
            for square in board.pieces(piece, chess.BLACK):
                    idx = numpy.unravel_index(square, (8, 8))
                    board3d[piece + 5][7 - idx[0]][idx[1]] = 1
        
          # add attacks and valid moves too
          # so the network knows what is being attacked
            aux = board.turn
            board.turn = chess.WHITE
            for move in board.legal_moves:
                i, j = square_to_index(move.to_square)
                board3d[12][i][j] = 1
                board.turn = chess.BLACK
            for move in board.legal_moves:
                i, j = square_to_index(move.to_square)
                board3d[13][i][j] = 1
            board.turn = aux
        
            return board3d
    
    import tensorflow.keras.models as models
    import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
    import tensorflow.keras.utils as utils
    import tensorflow.keras.optimizers as optimizers 
    
    def build_model(conv_size, conv_depth):
        board3d = layers.Input(shape=(14, 8, 8))
        
        #convolutional layers
        x = layers.Conv2D(filters=conv_size, kernel_size=3, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')(board3d)
        for _ in range(conv_depth):
            previous = x
            x = layers.Conv2D(filters=conv_size, kernel_size=3, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')(x)
            x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
            x = layers.Conv2D(filters=conv_size, kernel_size=3, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')(x)
            x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = layers.Add()([x, previous])
            x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
        x = layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(x)
    
        return models.Model(inputs=board3d, outputs=x)
    
    model = build_model(32, 4)
    utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False)
    
    import tensorflow.keras.callbacks as callbacks
    
    def get_dataset():
        container = numpy.load('dataset\\dataset.npz')
        b, v = container['b'], container['v']
        v = numpy.asarray(v / abs(v).max()/2 + 0.5, dtype=numpy.float32) #normalize 
        return b, v
    
    x_train, y_train = get_dataset()
    
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(5e-4), loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.summary()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=2048,
              epochs=1000,
              verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.1,
              callbacks=[callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', patience=10),
                         callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=15, min_delta=1e-4)])
    model.save('model.h5')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15172/3395566405.py in <module>
      1 model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(5e-4), loss='mean_squared_error')
      2 model.summary()
----> 3 model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      4           batch_size=2048,
      5           epochs=1000,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
```

Edit: Output log for model.summary()

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 14, 8, 8)]   0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 32, 8, 8)     4064        ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (BatchNorm  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
 alization)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)        (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_1 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_2[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 add (Add)                      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_1[0][0]',  
                                                                  'conv2d[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_1 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['add[0][0]']                    
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_2 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_3[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 activation_2 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_2[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_2[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_3 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_4[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 add_1 (Add)                    (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_3[0][0]',  
                                                                  'activation_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_3 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['add_1[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_3[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_4 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_5[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 activation_4 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_4[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_4[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_5 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_6[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 add_2 (Add)                    (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_5[0][0]',  
                                                                  'activation_3[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_5 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['add_2[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_5[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_6 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_7[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 activation_6 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_6[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 8, 8)     9248        ['activation_6[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_7 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 8, 8)    32          ['conv2d_8[0][0]']               
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 add_3 (Add)                    (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['batch_normalization_7[0][0]',  
                                                                  'activation_5[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 activation_7 (Activation)      (None, 32, 8, 8)     0           ['add_3[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 2048)         0           ['activation_7[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 1)            2049        ['flatten[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 80,353
Trainable params: 80,225
Non-trainable params: 128
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you post the log output of `model.summary()`?

Comment: @Noltibus I just edited the post. Does it have to do with my flatten? The dimensionality of the previous layers are all (, 32, 8, 8) and this clearly strikes an issue with matrix multriplication.

Comment: The `Flatten` layer is correct to reduce the dimensionality of your output data to 1. You could try to add `y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=1)` before feed the data into your network, although I don't think that it will fix something, but worth a try.

Comment: @Noltibus I added that, but the same error happens.

Comment: Anymore ideas? I'm still stuck.

Comment: I tried it again using the colab below the video you are using. Everything there works like a charm. What tensorflow version are you using? My colab uses 2.8.0, maybe you have a different one?
And can you add `print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)`

Comment: My TA ended up figuring it out, removing `data_format = channels_first` solved the issue. I was running on a Jupyter notebook, so I think the input order was different for `layers.Input(14,8,8)`

Answer (score 1):

`data_format = channels_first` was the culprit, after removing that the code executed flawlessly (the AI is not flawless though).